# I am having difficulty using Redirect and Link to change my React Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./components/App.jsx";
import SearchResults from "./components/SearchResults.jsx";
import history from "./history.js";
import SearchProvider from "./context/SearchContext.jsx";

const routing = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <SearchProvider>
          <Route path="/search" component={SearchResults} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        </SearchProvider>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("app"));
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../modules/app.module.css";
import Search from "./Search.jsx";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.appContainer}>
      <div className={styles.title}>BGrules</div>
      <Search />
      <Link to="/search">
        <button>Click me</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

SearchResults.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "../modules/searchResults.module.css";

const SearchResults = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.resultContainer}>
      <div className={styles.title}>Search Results</div>
      <div className={styles.subTitle}>results for term:</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

The problem I am having is that when I type the route /search in the url it is taking me to the correct page with no problem, but when I try and use Link or Redirect in my App file it will change the url but not load the component(just a blank white page)
I am not receiving any errors in the console.
I am new to asking questions here so hopefully I am asking this in a way that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What react-router-dom version are you using? I think you need to import BrowserRouter.

Comment: I am using 5.2. Would I need to import it in my index.jsx?

Comment: I mean, you need to do import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem recently, the cause was the history lib version, the current version of history is v5, but as pointed here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#documentation v5 is used with react-router v6.

To solve this issue I installed history v4 with: `yarn add history@^4` or `npm i history@^4`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was on history v5.0.0 and I uninstalled and changed to version 4.10.1 which solved the problem